# C-; not detected on GUI Emacs (weird behavior instead)

Tags: keystrokes

My issue is that Emacs 28.1 (from snap) or 27.1 (from apt) on Debian/sid Gnome 42.1 (on wayland) is not detecting the `C-;` keychord. Instead a bubble appear with already an `e` in it :

[image: Bubble popping when I hit C-; in Emacs]

It used to work, I used `C-x C-;` all the time to call `comment-line`, but it doesn't anymore. `emacs -q` is no help (same behavior).

I do are able to assign the `C-;` keychord to stuff in Gnome shortcut settings (but nothing was or is right now, I just did a test). I am also able to bind `C-;` to shortcuts in other programs.

I can't use `C-h k C-;`, the bubble is popping up when I hit `C-;`.

Why Emacs **(and only Emacs)** do this when I hit `C-;` ? What that thing popping up is ? How can I figure out what is going on ?

**Edit (solution) :**

It turns out I (or something) had enabled an IME (Input Method Editor). I was able to resolve my issue using `ibus-setup` and removing shortcuts in the Emoji section.

Comment: It sounds like this is something that your OS is doing, not Emacs. Does the same thing happen when you type `C-;` in other programs?

Comment: @Tyler no, it only happens in Emacs. Also "I do are able to assign the C-; keychord to stuff in Gnome shortcut settings. I am also able to bind C-; to shortcuts in other programs."

Comment: What is `C-;` assigned to in Gnome shortcut settings?

Comment: Nothing is ! I just assigned something temporarily to see if It worked. It worked. C-; is therefore seen by my OS and DE.

Comment: Do you see this problem if you start Emacs using `emacs -Q` (no init file)? If so, consider reporting it as a bug: `M-x report-emacs-bug`. If not, bisect your init file to find the culprit. If you still have a question after finding the culprit then pose it and delete this question, or edit this question to make it specific to what you found.

Comment: Thanks Fran. I was able to resolve my issue using `ibus-setup` and removing shortcuts in the `Emoji` section.